# WMIC command in batch complex username password not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd, passwords, wmic

I Write below script to know drive space of a remote system. If I run batch `filename.bat system_ip` from cmd, output will be generated. In script if I use simple username and password it's working fine, but if I given complex as given below username password in wmic it's won't work.

How to use complex password in wmic batch script? or how to modified this script to run in cmd along with `filename.bat system_ip username password`

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%~1"=="" goto help

@SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1" %%x IN ('"WMIC /user:"demo.admn" /password:"A$K0n!n2022" /node:"%1" LOGICALDISK GET Name " ') DO (
REM @ECHO %%x

@FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%n IN ('"WMIC /user:"demo.admn" /password:"A$K0n!n2022" /node:"%1" LOGICALDISK GET Name,Size,FreeSpace | find /i "%%x""') DO ( @SET FreeBytes=%%n & @SET TotalBytes=%%p

SET TotalGB=0
SET FreeGB=0

REM Parameter value used to convert in GB
set num1=1074

REM Parameter value used to convert in MB or KB
REM set num1 = 1049

REM @ECHO Total space: !TotalBytes!

SET /a TotalSpace=!TotalBytes:~0,-6! / !NUM1!
SET /a FreeSpace=!FreeBytes:~0,-7! / !NUM1!

SET TotalGB=!TotalSpace!
SET FreeGB=!FreeSpace!

SET PERNUM=100

SET /A TotalUsed=!TotalSpace! - !FreeSpace!
SET /A MULTIUSED=!TotalUsed!*!PERNUM!
SET /A PERCENTUSED=!MULTIUSED!/!TotalGB!

REM IF !TotalSpace! LSS 0 goto error

@echo.
@echo.
@echo %1  >>%cd%/log/%1.txt
@echo Drive: %%x >>%cd%/log/%1.txt
@ECHO =========================== >>%cd%/log/%1.txt
@ECHO Total space: !TotalGB! GB >>%cd%/log/%1.txt
@ECHO Free space : !FreeGB! GB >>%cd%/log/%1.txt
@ECHO PERCENTUSED : !PERCENTUSED! >>%cd%/log/%1.txt
@ECHO =========================== >>%cd%/log/%1.txt
REM @SET TotalSpace=
REM @SET FreeSpace=
REM @SET TotalUsed=
REM goto end
)
)
goto end
:error
echo.
echo *** Invalid server or drive specified ***
echo.
goto help

:help
echo.
echo diskfree.cmd
echo.
echo Queries remote server for free disk space.
echo Specify a MACHINENAME and a drive letter to be queried
echo.
echo Example: diskfree.cmd MACHINENAME c:
echo.
goto end

:end
```

Comment: You'll have to escape the `!` in the password as `^!` since you have delayed variable expansion enabled…

Comment: To begin with, I would start by removing your line `5`, and modifying line `4` to read `SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`. Then I would change your inefficient nested `FOR` loop _(lines `7` through `10`)_, to `@For /F "EOL=F Tokens=*" %%G In ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe /User:"demo.admn" /Password:"A$K0n!n2022" /Node:"%~1" LogicalDisk Where "FreeSpace Is Not Null" Get FreeSpace, Name, Size"') Do @For /F "Tokens=1-3" %%H In ("%%G") Do @(Set "FreeBytes=%%H" & Set "TotalBytes=%%J" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` Where your drive letter will now be `%%I`.